# Первый блин комом

Tags: значение-слов

Я вчера смотрел "Что? Где? Когда?" (укр. версию по каналу "1+1"). Там прозвучала странная, на мой взгляд, фраза.

Если коротко и упрощённо, то там надо было дополнить фразу "Первый блин ... ". И в качестве наводящего вопроса было: "Как на Руси называли медведя?". Минута на размышление :-)

Ответ (от ведущего) был таков. Что *первый блин комам*. А комам — это значит медведям. Так якобы в древней Руси называли медведей.

**Мой вопрос. Так каково же значение выражения "Первый блин комом"? Особенно последнего слова?**

Мне всегда казалось, что самое прямое. У начинающего, неопытного человека, первый блинчик может превратиться в комок. Если же речь о медведях, то где такое слово употреблялось? Когда? Какие остались однокоренные слова и вообще следы в славянской речи? Лично я не встречал такого.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Есть помимо совсем далёкой Японии ещё эстонский "kandma" и академик Рыбаков, считавший, что греки называли медведя "komos". Есть белорусский праздник  встречи весны, комоедица (камаедзіца), которое сторонники кома-медведя считают доказательством такого значения. Правда, например, Л. С. Клейн относит название праздника к слову "комедия", заимствованному белорусами через поляков. Ну, и ещё полный вариант пословицы "Первый блин - комам, второй – знакомым, третий – дальней родне, а четвертый – мне", от чего весь сыр-бор и возникает.

Лично мне подобная версия поговорки кажется сомнительной. Сомнительна эта версия хотя бы потому, что накормить медведя блинами в начале весны занятие или неэффективное, или крайне опасное. Медведю блины или не достанутся, или достанутся вместе с дарующим. Да и вообще, просыпаются медведи только в апреле, а масленица с блинами пораньше будет.

По-моему, если уж пытаться искать личность кому вышеприведённую пословицу логичнее интерпретировать, то тогда первый блин должен достаться ближайшим родственикам, которые почему-то не упомянуты в пословице вовсе, ну а далее по списку: друзьям, дальним родственикам и себя (а может и "меня", скомороха-прибауточника) не забыть. Так как для рифмы слово "комам" могли изменить до неузнаваемости, придумать изначальным можно что угодно.

Хотя всё это мне больше напоминает попытку философствований на ровном месте. На плохо нагретой сковородке, блин вздувается, встаёт комом, что гораздо логичнее всё объясняет, чем все эти заумствования.

Comment: Вспомнился анекдот.  
Встречает мужик в лесу медведя. Тот спрашивает:  
— Ты кто?  
Мужик отвечает:  
— Я турист.  
— А вот и нет, — говорит медведь, — это я турист. А ты — завтрак туриста. )))

Comment: А в Белоруссии именно блины пекут? Или изначально пекли что-то другое?

Comment: @gecube, и блины в том числе. Вообще, как почитал, комоедица с медведем связана сильно, [кое-где][1] даже считают, что это именно праздник пробуждения медведя. Правда учитывая, что медведя полагалось кормить, скатанной в комок гороховой кашей, название праздника особых затруднений не вызывает. Подробно о празднике, правда на белорусском можно прочитать [здесь][2]. Если белорусским владеете плохо, то гугл-переводчик даст вполне читабельный перевод.


  [1]: http://www.pribaikal.ru/obl-events/article/2781.html
  [2]: http://www.jivebelarus.net/our-heritage/kamaedzica.html

Comment: >Хотя всё это мне больше напоминает попытку философствований на ровном месте. На плохо нагретой сковородке, блин вздувается, встаёт комом, что гораздо логичнее, всё объясняет чем все эти заумствования.

Вот и меня "терзают смутные сомнения" насчёт того что, медведей на Руси называли комами. И насчёт того, что их блинами на Масленицу кормили.

Comment: А, так значит "медведи" - это не русские, а коми! :D